# Skip Specific Elements in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

[image]I'm pulling data from a webpage and I need to skip (not scrape) certain elements(embedded ads). Is there a method in selenium for this? My code looks like this

```
body = browser.find_element_by_class_name('wisbb_standardTable')
for row in body.find_elements_by_tag_name('tr'):
    row != body.find_elements_by_class_name('wisbb_tableRowAd')
    #print([td.text for td in row.find_elements_by_tag_name('td')])
    players.append([td.text for td in row.find_elements_by_tag_name('td')])
```

and I'm trying to find a way to do if `tag_name, x_path, class_name, etc.. = 'ads' skip`

Comment: no, selenium does not provide this, but regular python does. also we would need at least, an example of what you want and one you don't want. Once you figure that out, you can usually just do some sort of list comprehension like `[x for x in body.find_elements_by_tag_name('tr') where x.get_attribute('something') == 'something you want']` that will filter out the ones u dont want

Comment: @TehTris is this what you mean?

Comment: I added the html I just don't want to scrape the _tableRowAd part